# i cant seem to get my .append to loop this is what i have so far. I the while function as well

Tags: python, loops

i cant seem to get my .append to loop this is what i have so far. I the while function as well.

```
a = input('options '
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3.exit')
player = []
if a == 1: player.append('players name')
```

Comment: What exactly would you like to achieve? There is no loop in the code, what action should be repeated?

Comment: Can't actually anderstand, what did you try to achieve. If it's a infinite loop, just wrap this code with "while True:" block, and add "if a == 3: brake" to make it possible to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Input returns a string, not an int, so a will hold something like "1". So in your if statement the comparison had to be a=="1".

Comment: Side note: this only holds for Python 3, but if OP is using Python 2, the user input gets interpreted (and `raw_input()` is what should probably be used))

Answer (score 0):

Adding "a=int(a)" after input function is another way to solve problem, so that you can change data type of "a".

Answer (score 0):

okay so this is what i have so far. I got everything working except i need it to loop all the option till exiting.

```
a = input('options '
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3. Print roster.'
          '4. name correction'
          '5.exit')
player = []
while a == '1':
 player.append(input("players name"))
 a = input('options '
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3. Print roster.'
          '4. name correction'
          '5.exit')

  if a == '2':
    player.remove(input("players name"))
    a = input('options '
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3. Print roster.'
          '4. name correction'
          '5.exit')

  if a == '3':
   print(player)
   a = input("options enter"
             "1.add a player"
             "2.remove a player"
             "3. Print roster."
             "4. name correction"
             "5.exit")
  if a == '4':
   player.remove(input("players name to correct"))
   player.append(input('correction'))
   a = input('options enter'
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3. Print roster.'
          '4. name correction'
          '5.exit')
```

Answer (score -1):

i got it going now.

```
a = input('options '
      '1.add a player'
      '2.remove a player'
      '3.exit')
player = []
while a == '1':
  player.append(input("players name"))
  a = input('options '
          '1.add a player'
          '2.remove a player'
          '3.exit')



print(player)
```

Comment: and what would happen, if you'll type "2" ?

Comment: it would be false and close the program